# Unable to start cassandra service on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, cassandra

I got this output error :

```
[0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log instead.
intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred.
```

Comment: Read your message.  It tells you exactly what to do, replace `-Xloggc` by `-Xlog:gc` ...  This is not a question, just do it, you already have the answer.

Comment: I did this before asking my question sir, I replaced -Xloggc by -Xlog:gc  in all followings conf : cassandra-env.sh  jvm.options   cassandra.yaml ...
but the issue did not resolved

Comment: Cassandra will be compatible with Java 9/10/11 (and later) only in version 4.0 that isn't released yet

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by switching to java version 8.
When using java 9, 10 or other versions the only fix for now is use the openjdk-8-jre package.

Comment: I had to uninstall Java 10 in order to get Cassandra to proceed.